# 'File is too big' error when uploading QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, csv, file-formats, zip-codes

I have written a simple QGIS plugin which zooms the map canvas to a user specified UK postcode. I would like to share the plugin but the csv file, which contains stripped down OS Code-Point open data is just over 40mb. This is too large to upload to the qgis repository and impractical to download and share.

I have also tried storing the postcodes in a JSON file and pickle file, both of which are also to large a file size. Is there any alternative way of storing the postcodes which may result in a smaller file size?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a useful plug-in for QGIS users in GB. I don't think it would be asking too much of them if they had to download their own CodePoint Open data and put it somewhere where the plug-in could find it.

Comment: @nhopton This seems to be the the only solution, but still not ideal, if the OS change the schema of there Code Point CSV then the plugin would fail.

Comment: I suppose you could put the stripped-down Code Point data (as say a Spatialite db) somewhere on the Internet from where the plug-in could download it to local storage. As an aside, I was just wondering if there might be a procedure in OS OpenSpace that you could hijack to get the required data, but this isn't something I know anything about :(